# Не работает функция password_verify (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql, веб-программирование

Не робит функция, выдает false. Прошу помощи!

```
if (isset($_POST['VHButt'])) 
{
    if (empty($_POST["login"]) && empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
        echo "<p id='EnterLANDP'>Введите данные</p>";
    }
    else { 
        $loginEntr = $_POST["login"];
        $pass = $_POST["password"];
        $db = mysql_connect("localhost" ,"root", "") OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение ");
        mysql_select_db("mybase",$db);
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$db);
        $hash = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE login='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login'])."' LIMIT 1"));
        if (password_verify($pass, $hash['password'])) {
            echo "Вы вошли!";
        }
        else {
            echo "Вы не вошли!";
        }
        $db = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы проверяли содержимое `$hash`? Вы включали вывод предупреждений и ошибок php?

Comment: Содержимое проверял. Про подключение ошибок не совсем понял, можно по подробнее?

Comment: `mysql_` - то, что мертво, умереть не может? Как вы совместили его с password_verify? Какая у вас версия php?

Comment: 5.5 версия, качал недавно опен сервер, там эта и была

Comment: Поможет кто-нибудь?